# Should we close the old questions with only one answer by the original poster?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In recent months, I saw old questions, answered by the question owner and there was no another answer, in the Close Votes queue.

Close reason:

> This **problem cannot or can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the asker's circumstances may have rendered the question obsolete, or the question does not include a procedure to enable potential answerers to reproduce the same symptoms. Such questions are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers, but editing them to include more details can lead to re-opening.

I usually choose "**Leave Open**". Because another answer may be added by someone later, although it may not work for the OP.

Should we close them? Why?

Comment: Can you give examples of such questions?

Answer (score 12):

It would ultimately depend on the answer for me, but in general there is no problem with a self answered question.

Comment: I agree - the answer would need to answer the question, rather than just say "it worked after I restarted my PC" etc., but there is no problem with self-answering.  I encourage it

Comment: I know that no problem with a self answering question. What I wonder here whether we should close that kind of question appearing in the Close Votes queue recently.

Comment: I agree with this answer and @Midavalo. Self-answering is fine and encouraged but a particular answer and the particular question it is applied to may represent a problem that cannot or can no longer be reproduced in which case close and leave closed votes would be appropriate.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz _"This problem cannot or can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the asker's circumstances may have rendered the question obsolete"_ - this is the key here for the close reason.  If changes to circumstances etc. mean the question no longer is valid, then it should be closed.  If it's a valid question that could affect anybody, then it should be left open.  The act of self-answering is never the reason to close, it comes down to the answer itself.